# DataTables: Adding new row Requested unknown parameter 'id' for row 14

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

**AJAX**:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Dashboard",
            "url": "/",
            "icon": "icon-home",
            "child_of": null,
            "show": 1,
            "admin": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Submenu 3",
            "url": "http://stackoverflow.com",
            "icon": null,
            "child_of": null,
            "show": 1,
            "admin": 0
        },
    ]
}
```

**JS**:

```
$('#table-editable').dataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/api/menu",
        "type": "GET",
    },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "url" },
            { "data": "icon" },
            { "data": "child_of" },
            { "data": "show" },
            { "data": "admin" }
        ]
});
```

**So I'm using AJAX to fill up data in tables. It is working.**

I am using this: [DataTables: Inline Editing](https://datatables.net/blog/2012-05-31) for creating new row. (**Check Adding row & Edit Mode** in link)

### Problem:

Consider I've 13 rows. So IDs will be 1, 2, 3... 13.

While creating new row:
It does this: `oTable.fnAddData('', '',....);`
So when I add new row, it gives me error:

**DataTables warning: table id=table-editable - Requested unknown parameter 'id' for row 14. For more information about this error, please see datatables.net/tn/4**

So, basically it tries to fetch row id 14. But, there's no row with id 14.

## So what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [
    {
        "CategoryID": 1,
        "CategoryName": "Soler Power Plant",
        "CategoryProducts": [
        {
            "ID": 1,
            "Name": 'Commercial Solar Power Plant',
            "SubTitle": 'Eco, Eco Friendly, Energy, Green, Solar',
            "Brand": 'ACS',
            "Usage": '',
            "Type": '',
            "Price": 'Rs 5 Lakh / Unit',
            "Body_Material": '',
            "Description": 'Having a pre-determined quality administration system, we are thoroughly involved in delivering Commercial Solar Power Plant.',
            "ImageUrl": 'assets/images/Products/Sola-power-plant.jpg',
        },
        {
            "ID": 2,
            "Name": 'Industrial Solar Power Plants',
            "SubTitle": 'Eco Friendly, Save Energy',
            "Brand": 'ACS',
            "Usage": '',
            "Type": '',
            "Price": 'Rs 5 Lakh / Unit',
            "Body_Material": '',
            "Description": 'So as to become a preferential business name, we are thoroughly engrossed in shipping an inclusive collection of Industrial Solar Power Plants.',
            "ImageUrl": 'assets/images/Products/Industrial_Solar_Power_Plants.jpg',
        },
         {
             "ID": 3,
             "Name": 'On Grid Solar Plant',
             "SubTitle": 'Eco Friendly, Save Energy',
             "Brand": 'ACS',
             "Usage": '',
             "Type": '',
             "Price": 'Rs 1.1 Lakh / Unit',
             "Body_Material": '',
             "Description": "We are the leading firm of On Grid Solar Plant. To sustain the quality, our products are made under the guidance of industry certified professionals.",
             "ImageUrl": 'assets/images/Products/On_Grid_Solar_Plant.jpg',
         },
          {
              "ID": 4,
              "Name": 'On Grid Solar Power Plant',
              "SubTitle": 'Eco Friendly, Save Energy',
              "Brand": 'ACS',
              "Usage": '',
              "Type": '',
              "Price": 'Rs 5 Lakh / Unit',
              "Body_Material": '',
              "Description": "We are the leading firm of On Grid Solar Power Plant. To sustain the quality, our products are made under the guidance of industry top professionals.",
              "ImageUrl": 'assets/images/Products/On_Grid_Solar_Power_Plant.jpg',
          },
          {
              "ID": 5,
              "Name": 'Solar Power Plant',
              "SubTitle": 'Eco Friendly, Save Energy',
              "Brand": 'ACS',
              "Usage": '',
              "Type": '',
              "Price": 'Rs 5 Lakh / Unit',
              "Body_Material": '',
              "Description": "We are the leading firm of Solar Power Plant. To sustain the quality, our products are made under the guidance of industry certified professionals.",
              "ImageUrl": 'assets/images/Products/Solar_Power_Plant.jpg',
          },
        ]
    }
]




 function GetProducts() {

            var products = data;

            $.each(products, function () {

                //var product = products.filter(filterByID)
                var product = this;
                $('#ProductDetails').append('<h2 class="text-center">' + this.CategoryName + '</h2>');
                var details = product;
                $.each(details.CategoryProducts, function () {


                    tempData = tempData + '<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">' +
                                    '<div class="project-box">' +
                                        '<div class="frame-outer">' +
                                            '<div class="frame">' +
                                                '<img style="width:350px;" src="' + this.ImageUrl + '" class="attachment-340x220 size-340x220 wp-post-image" alt="">' +
                                            '</div>' +
                                        '</div>' +
                                        '<div class="text-box">' +
                                            '<h3><a>' + this.Name + '</a></h3>' +
                                            '<div class="tags-row">' +
                                                '<a class="link">' + this.SubTitle + '</a>' +
                                            '</div>' +
                                            '<p>' + this.Description + '</p>' +
                                            //'<a href="javascript:ViewMore(' + this.ID + ')" class="btn-readmore">More Details</a>' +
                                        '</div>' +
                                    '</div>' +
                                '</div>';
                });

                $('#ProductDetails').append('<div class="row">' + tempData + '</div>');
                tempData = '';

            });
        }
```

Here, it's my own code may be it's help you

Comment: if your data is static then you can use this.